# Firebase Realtime Database Rules: Validation is cascading to child. How to ignore .validate on parent node?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to write firebase realtime database rules that firstly, allow a new game to be created if the `$gameID` has exactly 6 characters AND the `$gameID` doesn't already exist on the `games` node. This rule actually validates perfectly when creating a new game.

The problem comes when a player then tries to join that game: the aforementioned validate rule denies them because it requires the game to not exist - but I only want that rule — `"$gameID.length === 6 && !data.exists()"` — to validate the writes ONLY on `games/$gameID`, not on `games/$gameID/players`.

My understanding was that `.validate` rules don't cascade down, so why is it not allowing the write to `games/$gameID/players`?

My current `database.rules` file is:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "games": {
      "$gameID": {
        ".read": "auth !== null",
        ".write": "auth !== null",
        ".validate": "$gameID.length === 6 && !data.exists()",
          "players": {
          ".read": "auth !== null",
          ".write": "auth !== null"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The javascript code for the `players` write is:

```
await push(ref(db, `games/${gameID}/players`), playerName)
```

`set` simulation denied **with** `.validate` rule (`$gameID` node `ABC123` **exists** in database):
[image: Denied with .validate rule]

`set` simulation allowed **without** `.validate` rule (`$gameID` node `ABC123` **exists** in database):
[image: Allowed without .validate rule]

Comment: That second snippet can't work. Since in your JSON the `players` node is under the `games/$gameID`, it must be under there in the rules too. I recommend removing the second rules snippet from your question to prevent it acting as a red herring (as it did for me).

Comment: I think your `root.child('games').child($gameID).exists() === false` can be simplified to `!data.exists()`.

Comment: You seem to assume that it's the `.validate` rule that is causing the rejection. Did you validate that, but removing that rules and seeing if the write then succeeds?

Comment: I removed the second rule snippet from the original question - thanks. And the `!data.exists()` snippet is a great tip - thanks again. And yes, I've tried removing the `.validate` rule and the code works perfectly — so I'm 99% sure that `.validate` on the parent `$gameID` is the problem

Comment: Thanks for that. Let's see if we can get that to 100% certainty :) Can you change your code to: 1) log `gameID`, 2) log `auth.currentUser.uid`, and then include the updated minimal rules, the updated code, and its output in your question?

Comment: When you say "change your code" do you mean my javascript code on the client? If so then yes - I console logged the `gameID` and it returns the expected string. And `auth.currentUser.uid` also returns a valid `uid` identifier (rv9mEVrTaINVWheRJahLDFR00Ctd)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact code and output. I don't immediately see what's going wrong anymore (maybe someone else does), so am hoping that the code + output will give some insight.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not the code anywhere else — I think it's an isolated problem to just the database rules. The reason I'm so confident about that is because the same behaviour occurs in the Rules Playground in the Firebase Console. I've added images to the original question to highlight my point.

Comment: I just don't get what's going wrong. I use similar rules ` "69921744": { "$gameID": { ".validate": "$gameID.length === 6 && !data.exists()" }, ".write": true }` and then test writing to `/69921744/gameid/players`, and it works fine. I hope somebody spots what's going on. :-/

Comment: Thanks for trying Frank. Have you replicated my rules exactly in the Rules Playground and got different results to me?

Comment: I used the rules I shared in my previous comment. Not exactly the same, but I thought they'd be equivalent.

Comment: But did you actually have a `69921744` node with a `gameid` node in your _actual_ database?

Comment: Good point . When the node exists the validation rule rejects a write to the path. That seems expected, right?

Comment: No, the rule should allow a `gameid` (or `$gameID`) to be created if it's length === 6 AND if this particular `gameid` — let's say `ABC123` — doesn't already exist. This part of the rule is there to stop any duplicate game ids. But then writes to `games/$gameID/players` are denied because the rule is saying _"hang on, this `gameid` already exists!"_ But my understanding was that `.validate` rules don't cascade, so why is it validating on writes to its children?

Answer (score 1):

When security rules talk of "cascading rules", this refers to the behaviour where a higher tier `".read"` and `".write"` rule will override any nested rules (a higher tier rule succeeding will override a nested rule failing). This is in contrast to `".validate"` rules where every rule in the chain must evaluate to `true` for a write to succeed (a higher tier rule succeeding will not override a nested rule failing).

From your comments your data looks like this:

```json
{
  "games": {
    "abcdef": {
      "players": {
        "-MoSHoV6kC4cV_jCdssT": "player A",
        "-MoSI4begYNOBYVmiVBi": "not player A",
        "-MoSI5nVWYD5VnSaaWP0": "tom"
      }
    },
    /* more rooms */
  }
}
```

The problem with your current rules is that you must allow the room to be created, and you must also allow players to join that room. As you've deduced, your rules permit the first action, but block the second.

To fix this, you'll need to make a slight tweak to your client-based code so that you can differentiate the "I am creating this room" and the "I am joining this room" actions. With the current structure, I do not see how this is possible as the two actions don't have anything different between them - they both look like:

```
SET /games/abcdef/players/-MoSHoV6kC4cV_jCdssT = "some user"
SET /games/abcdef/players/-MoSI4begYNOBYVmiVBi = "not player A"
```

Which of these requests should be allowed to create the room?

To help this, we need to introduce a way to tell the database that "I am creating this room". We can do this by adding a new "owner" property which allows us to apply the following rules:

- If the owner doesn't exist, allow room creation.
- If the owner already exists, deny room creation.
- If the room is created without an owner, deny room creation.
- If the room is created with an invalid ID, deny room creation.
- Players may only be added/removed by the owner.

Because your users are signed in, you should use their user ID instead of a push ID to help with keeping rooms secure later on, although the below setup will still work even if you don't switch.

```json
{
  "games": {
    "abcdef": {
      "players": {
        "BzzmNyT7hlMz3ElRLMYS0jaGKgE3": "player A",
        "BSfHksARFnYco5LenfxevOpnwe63": "not player A",
        "vDnPE4DqE3cz1IYHwXQvDFw3W7r2": "tom"
      },
      "owner": "BzzmNyT7hlMz3ElRLMYS0jaGKgE3"
    },
    /* more rooms */
  }
}
```

with the rules:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "games": {
      "$gameID": {
        // any authenticated user may read this entire room's data
        // future: restrict to only members?
        ".read": "auth !== null",

        // a room must have an ID of 6 characters
        // and must have an owner assigned to it
        ".validate": "$gameID.length === 6 && newData.hasChild('owner')",

        "players": {
          // use $pushId here if keeping your "push" method instead of switching to user IDs
          "$playerId": {
            // only the owner may add/remove players
            ".write": "auth !== null && newData.parent().child('owner').val() == auth.uid",
            // as long as the value is a string
            ".validate": "newData.isString()"
          }
        },

        "owner": {
          // an owner prop can be created, but not edited/deleted
          ".write": "auth !== null && !data.exists()"
          // an owner prop must be the writer's user ID
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val() === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** The above rules to nothing to asset that the owner of a room is also a player.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer. It helped me to understand Firebase RTD rules a bit better. The one thing I didn't mention in my initial question — and I'm not sure if/how it affects your reply — is that the room/game creator is _**not**_ also a player; they are simply the host, therefore the room/game is initially created with no players in it. And also, the rule that you introduced where only the owner/host can add players is not something that will work for my game. My main focus with this overall rule was to not allow **duplicate** room/game IDs from being accidentally created.

Comment: @BenClarke You should add all that information to the question. There's only so much we can extrapolate from what you've provided. What data is written when creating a room? Who are the players? Are they anonymous (e.g. like a Jackbox Party game)? Do players need to be logged in? How are new players added?  Who can add new players? Can players remove themselves? etc.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but I'm just looking for a database rule that will prevent a room/game from being created if it already exists. I thought this would be a standard requirement for many Firebase developers? In MySQL there is a primary key which only allows unique ids for each row - I was hoping Firebase would have a similar feature within the database rules.

Comment: @BenClarke I get where you are coming from, but without knowing **what data** you are writing to the database and in **what order**, I can't tell how to identify the difference between someone "creating a room" vs. "joining a room" here. Firebase does support this (e.g. chat rooms with a member list), but there's missing information that's needed to reach a solution. The solution I proposed here makes the requests different, which then allows you to properly block the request if two different users are trying to create the same room. Answer the questions above, and I'll be able to adjust this.

Comment: I didn't realise it would be this hard for Firebase to provide a simple uniqueness rule. I've now just added the validation client-side. Not ideal because there's always the chance of an edge case. But I now just keep a record of each room/game ID in an `active_games` node on the root of the db. Then I check this path client-side before a new game is created to see if any `active_games` have the room/game ID that is about to be used. If the check returns `null` then it's "safe" to continue. If the check returns not null then I generate another 6-digit code on the client and retry.

Comment: @BenClarke As I've explained 3 different ways already, your "simple uniqueness rule" is performing to specification - exactly as you've written it - you may create a room but noone can edit it once it's created (which includes nested data). If you want to be able to change the nested data, you **must** provide the code you use to create the room **as well as** the code used to add players so we can see ways we can prevent someone overwriting an existing room. To give a blunt analogy, you're asking us to do a simple tyre change without specifying whether it's for a car, a truck or an aeroplane.